# Newly Formed Non Resident UK LLP Form SA401 and SA402

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm not resident of UK or EU and I've newly formed a two membered UK LLP as non resident with me as a member and a single member US LLC as the other designated member.
After one week of forming the LLP I've received a letter from HRMC on the registered address asking me to complete form SA401 and SA402 or there will be penalty.
At the end of the letter it is stated that I don't need to file a Tax return If I am not resident and have no UK presence which is true in my situation.

My question is:
Should I ignore this letter as both designated members of the LLP are non UK with no UK presence?
Is there a way to inform HRMC online of my situation or by FAX?

The company has no UK presence or connected income.
Thank you